# What's the 64-bit equivalent of `Get-wmiobject win32_service`?

Tags: powershell, service

I'm using powershell to get a list of services from several computers to see which ones use the administrator to run.

So far I have:

`Get-wmiobject win32_service | Select -Property startName, Name, systemname`

But it seems to me that this would only cover 32-bit services.  How do I get a complete list of services from the `Get-wmiobject` command in powershell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will still work on 64 and display those services - name just wasn't changed for compatibility reasons and works the same regardless of bitness

Comment: +1 because its what I wanted to hear

Comment: -1 this is what you wanted to hear but it'n not true: 64-bit are not listed under `win32_service`